# Disable a subform while editing data in another subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two subforms, the first is a list and the second is a detail record of the record selected in the first subform.

When I select the edit button in the detail subform I want to lock out the list form.

I tried: `forms!master!subformList.enabled=false`.

Note:

- `_D` is the detailed subform.
- `_L` is the list subform.
- `cmb_Edit` is the edit/save button located on detail subform.

```
Private Sub EnableFutureForm(EF)
    Select Case EF
        Case 1                  'SubForm Detail is Locked Down
            FuturePaint (False)
            Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_D!cmb_Edit.Caption = "Edit"
            Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_L.Form.Enabled = True

        Case 2                  'SubForm Detail is Opened up
            FuturePaint (True)
            Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_D!cmb_Edit.Caption = "Save"
            Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_L.Form.Enabled = False
            Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_D!cmb_TRMM.SetFocus
    End Select
End Sub
```

I want the list subform to not respond to any click, while the `Form_Click` continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable events by setting the forms property.
For`Form_Click`it is [Form.OnClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.onclick) property.

```vb
'disable event
Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_L.Form.OnClick = vbNullString
'enable event
Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_L.Form.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
```

Or you can add a check to the events-code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Click()
If Forms!FrmFutureWork!FrmFutureWork_L.Enabled then
' Actions on subform-control (not the form!) enabled
Else
' Action on subform-control disabled 
End IF
End Sub
```